# cannot Run Multiple spiders in scrapy at same time

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, scrapy

I am doing scrapy project I want run multiple spiders at same time This is code for run spiders from script

```
from spiders.product_spider import ProductSpider
from spiders.another_spider import AnotherSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from butik.butik import settings as my_settings


crawler_settings = Settings()
crawler_settings.setmodule(my_settings)
process = CrawlerProcess(settings=crawler_settings)

process.crawl(ProductSpider)
process.crawl(AnotherSpider)
process.crawl(AnotherSpider)
process.crawl(ProductSpider)

process.start()
```

but the problem is when running the file it takes along time (if i run two spiders takes 50 seconds, and if run 4 spiders takes 1:40 min)

> note: I'm  download the page from selenium

Comment: Isn’t it possible that Selenium is the bottleneck here? Even if those 4 spiders run asynchronously, they depend on the same instance of Selenium, right? (I’ve never used Selenium with Scrapy, so I’m not sure how it works)

Comment: use , i think that too, i tested it without selenium and it's ok